# Set color of text in status bar it is not working (swift 3 - iOS 10)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

My status bar is black and I'm trying to set as white, so I did what I found in some questions here and put this on my AppDelegate...

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    //Status bar color
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

    return true
}
```

There is no error in my console, nothing about this. The status bar text is still black. What could be causing this? There is another way to do that in swift 3.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ensure once  in your project **info.plist** the row 
**View controller-based status bar appearance** and set it to **NO**

[image]

Comment: It was that. Thanks you!

Comment: hey! can we set a custom color ? I mean I want red or green any color besides light content or black content ?

Comment: @theEmqe - no we can't, n this place hide the status bar use your own view

Answer (score 0):

In Swift3 you have to use following code, put anywhere in your view controller

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is [Apple Guidelines/Instruction](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/status-bars/) about status bar change. Only Dark & light (while & black) are allowed in status bar.

*Here is - How to change status bar style:*

If you want to set status bar style, application level then set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `NO` in your `.plist' file.

if you wan to set status bar style, at view controller level then follow these steps:

1. Set the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `YES` in the `.plist` file, if you need to set status bar style at UIViewController level only.
2. In the viewDidLoad add function - `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate`
3. override preferredStatusBarStyle in your view controller.

-

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```